# What it is the best performance way to grab duplicates from a large Set<String>?

Tags: java, set, duplicates

I have a large `Set<String>` that contains many words, say:

**"aaa, cCc, dDD, AAA, bbB, BBB, AaA, CCc, ..."**

I want to group all duplicate words from the Set ignoring the case sensitivity of the words then save them in a `Vector<Vector<String>>` or whatever, so each `Vector<String>` item will contain the group of similar words, like this :

`Vector<String>`: **aaa, AAA, AaA, ...**

`Vector<String>`: **cCc, CCc, ...**

`Vector<String>`: **bbB, BBB, ...**

I care about the performance as this Set contain many words.

Comment: 1/ Do you know the full list of target strings in advance?

Comment: 2/ Why are you using Vector instead of ArrayList or LinkedList?

Comment: Can you replace the "Set" implementation to sort the values into an internal structure when they're 'add'ed to the Set in the first place. I realize this isn't what you asked but seems like maybe switching your collection implementation may make this easier.

Comment: *"I care about the performance as this Set contain many words."* Do you care enough to have run a profiler on it, or are you just guessing?

Comment: If you care about performance, don't use the thread-safe Vector; Use ArrayList or HashSet instead.

Comment: @Brad, you have about 20 questions without an accepted answer.  Perhaps you could ask questions in way they can be reasonably answered or follow up answers so they can be accepted.

Comment: @Matthew: The list of words is variable. It may change from time to time. Thanks for the advice, i will not use a Vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a `HashMap<String, Vector<String>> hashMap`.
Next, for each 'string' in your set

```
if (!hashMap.containsKey(string.toLowerCase()){
     Vector v = new Vector();
     v.add(string);
      hashMap.put(string.toLowerCase(), v);
} else { 
     hashMap.get(string.toLowerCase()).add(string);
}
```

At the end, create a Vector of vectors if needed, or work with the hashmap.valueSet()

Comment: Thanks a lot ... I've made some changes, like in case some of the words in the Set have no duplicates, so no need to add them to the HashMap.

Answer (score 2):

If you truly care about performance you would not use `Vector`. As for the sorting problem one solution would be to use the `TreeMap` or `TreeSet` object and create a `Comparator` that does the equality (sorting) you want.

The instantiation could be:

```
new TreeMap<String,LinkedList<String>>(new Comparator<String>() {

   // comparator here

});
```

Usage:

```
LinkedList<String> entry = map.get(nextKey);
if (entry == null) {
  entry = new LinkedList<String>()
  map.put(nextKey, entry);
}
entry.add(nextKey);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can choose `Set` implementation you can use `TreeSet` with `Comparator` that compares strings ignoring case. Then you will be able to iterate over sorted list and easily group duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

This iterates over the input set once and I doubt you can get much faster than that. Swapping the `ArrayList`s for `LinkedLists` may trade locality for less copying, which may be an performance gain, but I doubt it. Here's the code:

```
Set<String> input = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(
    "aaa", "cCc", "dDD", "AAA", "bbB", "BBB", "AaA", "CCc"));

Map<String, List<String>> tmp = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

for (String s : input) {
    String low = s.toLowerCase();
    List<String> l = tmp.get(low);

    if (l == null) {
        l = new ArrayList<String>();
        tmp.put(low, l);
    }

    l.add(s);
}

final List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<List<String>>(tmp.values());
```